No log file from Portsentry
I am having difficulty accessing the Portsentry scan history. When I try to view it using
/var/lib/portsentry/portsentry.history

I get the following error in the terminal:
bash: /var/lib/portsentry/portsentry.history: No such file or directory

Yet Porsentry still functions properly :
sudo systemctl status portsentry
● portsentry.service - LSB: # start and stop portsentry
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/portsentry; generated)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-08-08 14:10:39 CEST; 32min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 735 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/portsentry start (code=exited, status=0/>
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 18970)
     Memory: 7.5M
        CPU: 1.634s
     CGroup: /system.slice/portsentry.service
             ├─813 /usr/sbin/portsentry -atcp
             └─821 /usr/sbin/portsentry -audp

I have allowed Portsentry to start on each reboot.
sudo systemctl enable portsentry
portsentry.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install.  
 Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable portsentry

Then, I added the following to the file /etc/portsentry/portsentry.conf
#LOG FILE
LOGGING=1
LOG_FILE=/var/log/portsentry.log
LOG_FORMAT=timestamp,ip,protocol,port,action

I restarted Portsentry and checked for a LOG file, but still couldn't find anything.
/var/log/portsentry.log 
bash: /var/log/portsentry.log: No such file or directory

